# how to make this work ? CASE & LIMIT

Tags: php, sql, limit, case

Trying to use a case statement to control the operation of limit.

Sample query of what I'm trying to do:

```
ORDER BY bider_price
DESC LIMIT 
(CASE WHEN id_bid_writer = "'.$_SESSION['id_member'].'"
    THEN 0,1
    ELSE 0,2
END)
```

Comment: Can you describe, more conceptually, what it is you're trying to do here?

Comment: when the seller watch to page then show only the MAX bid (limit 0,1)
if the bider watch the page then show his bid (limit 0,2)

Comment: I don't even know if you can use case there but you can try `THEN 1` and `ELSE 2` without `0,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose LIMIT values outside of SQL, in your PHP script. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl "
       "LIMIT ".($logged_in ? "0,1" : "0,2");
```

Otherwise it makes no sense

Comment: OK SO THIS IS THE LOGIC SOLUTION THEN

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by conditional statement by php code ..

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT ".($logged_in ? "0,1" : "0,2");